# Android: Button representing "get my position!"

Tags: android, layout, button

I have a EditBox, and on right side of this EditBox I wan't to put a Button representing "Get My Position".

User clicks on this button, and my application get his position and fills EditBox with it.

I found a Compass and added on a ImageButton, but I don't know if this really represent the idea.

[image: EditBox + Compass]

Anyone knows a better button to represent "Get My Position"?

Thanks

Comment: you want button image? like baloon in google?

Comment: Baloon is a overlay on the map, not? I want a button that user understand that when he clicks on it, the application will get his position...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Button looks ok, and will be recognized by most users. If you want to get the System-default (the picture of the Drawalbe may differ on roms from HTC, Samsung Motorola etc) you can get it with

```
getResources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_location)
```

Always check for non-Null here. You can download the standart Android location Button [here](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/), (ic_menu_location), as a fallback, if the `getDrawable()` call fails

Answer (score 0):

I used a 'globe' in my application. If the EditBox is blank until the user requests their location, why not use the put some default text inside it requesting the user to click the button?

Comment: Because, the user can type the address or get by his position

Comment: Yeah, if you put something like "Type your location, or press the button to the right".